# maintain `new` in url after validation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, validation, redirect

from the default scaffold generator I have the following `create` action in my blogs controller:

```
  # POST /blogs
  # POST /blogs.json
  def create
    @blog = Blog.new(params[:blog])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @blog.save
        format.html { redirect_to @blog, notice: 'Blog was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @blog, status: :created, location: @blog }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @blog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

When the sent form contains errors, my browser is redirected to `/blogs` URL but in the page the `new` action is rendered.

This is really ugly in my opinion and (also to simplify my javascript) I would like the browser to remain in the same `blogs/new` URL.

I tried with changing `redirect_to :new` instead of `render action: "new"`, but this of course loses the `@blog` data.

any clue on how to do this?

thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Rails 3, when a resource create action fails and calls render :new, why must the URL change to the resource's index url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490098/in-rails-3-when-a-resource-create-action-fails-and-calls-render-new-why-must)

Comment: Indeed the question is very similar. and the reply that's here currently is also already present in that question too. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep new in your path you could redirect with params like so:

`redirect_to new_blog_path(blog: params[:blog])`

and then check for these params in blog#new

Comment: Thanks nice idea, but the call is a `GET` and having all these parameters in the URL doesn't work, I get: `Request-URI Too Large` exception.