# Create Function Not Redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am somewhat new to Rails, and I am learning off of a tutorial online. The guy in the videos talked about how you have to have an if statement to decide if the save worked or not.

This is my code:

```
def create
  @quiz = Quiz.new(quiz_params)
  if @quiz.save
    flash[:notice] = "Your quiz has been created."
    redirect_to action: 'index'
  else
   render('new')
  end
end
```

The quiz_params was defined as such:

```
params.require(:quiz).permit(:title, :summary, :visible)
```

For some reason, it refuses to redirect to the index function, deciding to stay on the same page while the URL changes from `localhost:3000/quizzes/new` to `localhost:3000/quizzes`.

The guy who taught the tutorial had this code.

```
def create
  @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)
  if @subject.save
    flash[:notice] = "Subject created succesfully."
    redirect_to(subjects_path)
  else
    render('new')
  end
end
```

The subject_params went as such:

```
 params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :position, :visible)
```

Other than the wording in the quotes and the name of the model and variables, I am not sure what the difference is. I am being as consistent as I can, so there shouldn't be any difference.

Sorry if the formatting is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `rake routes` on your `command prompt` then they see what is the `index_path` if got to `redirect` to the home page then write

```
redirect_to root_path #=> Or root_url
```

Or if your controller is `QuizzesController` then your `index` path is `quizzes_path`

```
redirect_to quizzes_path #=> Use instead of redirect_to action: 'index'
```

Or if you have `articles/index` then

```
redirect_to articles_path
```

Hope to help

Comment: It just renders new and changes the URL, even after running rake routes. It, for some reason, stays on the new template while going to /quizzes.

Comment: Have you used "remote: true" on the form?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you use `remote: true` on form for ajax request then I think have to some problem but if you did use that then you need to debug `create` action code I think on `create` method not saving the data if date saved then `redirect_to quizzes_path` work if not saving the data then `render` `new` action

Comment: But where would I put remote: true

Comment: You don't need to this now, you need to debug now why not saving data, because if data save then you redirected to index page

Answer (score 0):

Your validation fails and it renders 'new' view. while action remains to create.

If you will see rake routes this route corresponds to localhost:3000/quizzes to create action.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490098/in-rails-3-when-a-resource-create-action-fails-and-calls-render-new-why-must) answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) to debug the request and see if the code is calling `redirect_to` or not. it could be an ajax form as @fool said. check the form object in the view if it has `remote: true` attribute, delete it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell us Rails and Ruby version. Anyway I am using Rails 5+ and I think the syntax

```
Render('new')
```

Is old or deprecated. What I do usually is this.

```
def create
    plan = Plan.new plan_params
    plan.delivered = 0
    plan.user_id = params['u_id']
    if plan.save
      flash[:OK] = 'Il nuovo piano e\' stato salvato con successo!'
    else
      flash[:err] = 'Siamo spiacenti ma non siamo riusciti a registrare il tuo piano, ricontrolla i dati inseriti!'
      flash[:errors] = plan.errors.messages
    end
    redirect_to plans_users_path(User.find(params['u_id']))
end
```

So my advice is try to use named paths instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Change below line in controller:

```
redirect_to action: 'index'
```

with

```
redirect_to "/quizzes"
```

So the code be like:

```
def create
  @quiz = Quiz.new(quiz_params)
  if @quiz.save
    redirect_to "/quizzes", notice: "Your quiz has been created."
  else
   render 'new'
  end
end
```