# Using responders gem with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using [**responders gem**](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) to dry up my controllers. Here's my current code:

```
class OfficehoursController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @officehour = Officehour.new
  end

  def create
    @officehour = Officehour.create(officehour_params)

    respond_with(@officehour, location: officehours_path)
  end

  def officehour_params
    params.require(:officehour).permit(:end, :start, :status)
  end
end
```

The problem that I'm facing right now is:

When I send valid parameters to `create`, it redirects to `officehours/` as expected, however when I get 422 (validation error), it changes the URL from `officehours/new` to `officehours/` (however it stays at the form page... idk why). The same happens for edit/update actions.

So, I want to stay at the `.../new` or `.../edit` when I get 422 error, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the issue comes from the gem. It just follows [RESTFUL API](https://gist.github.com/alexpchin/09939db6f81d654af06b), so does `Rails`.

That means the path for creating `office hours` is `/officehours`. Let's talk about your case:

- There is nothing to say when we creating successfully. In your case, you redirect users to `officehours_path`.
- When we creating **unsuccessfully**, we need to re-render the error form to users. But we were rendering the form in `create` action. As I said above, the URL for creating is `/officehours`, so you will see the `/officehours` instead of `officehours/new`

---

In order to keep the url `/officehours/new`:

- We can set `/officehours/new` instead of `/officehours` for `:create` action. But you **should not** do that, are we going to break `RESTFUL API`?
- Creating via `AJAX` to keep the URL persisted and you have to handle everything, eg: set flash messages on client, using Javascript to redirect in case of success, render the form error in case failure, ... And I don't think the gem help you dry up your application anymore.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that it's a problem in responders gem, as I've noticed the same in rails applications. It seems like the default behaviour of rails applications.
take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490098/in-rails-3-when-a-resource-create-action-fails-and-calls-render-new-why-must) for the explanation.